# How does GCC process quotes in macro?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, macros

I'm trying to test gcc preprocessor for its macro expansion.

I write following code: (just for testing)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define QUOTE "
#define TMPL hello

int main(){
    printf(QUOTE TMPL QUOTE);
    return 0;
}
```

the compiling result is:

```
$ gcc main.c -o main
main.c:3:15: warning: missing terminating " character
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:7: error: missing terminating " character
main.c:7: error: missing terminating " character
main.c:7: error: ‘hello’ undeclared (first use in this function)
main.c:7: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
main.c:7: error: for each function it appears in.)
main.c:7: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
main.c:7: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
$
```

Then I try to have a look at the preprocessed result

```
$ gcc -E main.c -o tmp.c
main.c:3:15: warning: missing terminating " character
$
```

Though giving a warning, it somehow produces correct preprocessed code in `tmp.c`

```
int main(){
 printf(" hello ");
 return 0;
}
```

And I compiler `tmp.c`, `hello` is correctly printed.

I'm wondering why `gcc -E` could produce correct code, while using `gcc` compiling directly failed. Is there difference between the two method of gcc preprocessor?

```
$ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

Comment: A preprocessor macro should expand into a sequence of lexer tokens. So you can't have a macro like `#define QUOTE "`; BTW, your GCC version is very old, current one is 4.8

Comment: You want to google "c preprocessor stringize".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, a preprocessor macro should expand into a sequence of lexer tokens. Withing GCC source code, the `libcpp` (in charge of preprocessing and tokenizing) is producing a stream of tokens (not plain chars). A recent GCC 4.8, when run as `gcc -Wall endyul.c -o endyl` on your example, gives quite helpful diagnostics:

```
endyul.c:3:15: warning: missing terminating " character [enabled by default]
 #define QUOTE "
               ^
endyul.c: In function 'main':
endyul.c:7:5: error: missing terminating " character
     printf(QUOTE TMPL QUOTE);
     ^
endyul.c:7:5: error: missing terminating " character
endyul.c:4:14: error: 'hello' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define TMPL hello
              ^
endyul.c:7:18: note: in expansion of macro 'TMPL'
     printf(QUOTE TMPL QUOTE);
                  ^
endyul.c:4:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
 #define TMPL hello
              ^
endyul.c:7:18: note: in expansion of macro 'TMPL'
     printf(QUOTE TMPL QUOTE);
                 ^
```

Your GCC 4.2 is very old. You should consider upgrading it.

And `clang` (3.3) gives also a good diagnostic:

```
 clang -Wall endyul.c -o endyul   
 endyul.c:3:15: warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
 #define QUOTE "
               ^
 endyul.c:7:12: error: expected expression
     printf(QUOTE TMPL QUOTE);
            ^
 endyul.c:3:15: note: expanded from macro 'QUOTE'
 1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

Read  again the [CPP manual of GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/), notably the chapters on [Stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) and [Concatenation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html).

Comment: Because `gcc -E` don't produce code, but text, which happens to look correct (but is not). C preprocesssing is defined to produce a stream of tokens (in the previous century, old compilers before the C99 standard had preprocessors producing text; the standard mandates that preprocessing should produce tokens, not plain text).